# Scanner.skip("[\r\n]+") not reading end of the line exception: java.util.NoSuchElementException

Tags: java, jpa, java.util.scanner

So I’m trying read a csv file to my (java)jpa project using scanner, the problem is that once it gets to the end of the line, it reads the \n and it gives me an exception, I've tried using the method `scanner.skip("[\r\n]+")`, but even then it doesn’t work properly. I'm using `scanner.next()`, since I’m using Delimiter, so the method `nextLine()` won't be helpful for me in this case. Can anybody help me?

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner (new File(loq)).useDelimiter(";");
pote = sc.next();
Questoes quest = new Questoes( ); 
do
{
  EntityManagerFactory quest_factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("TRM");
  EntityManager entitymanager = quest_factory.createEntityManager( );
  entitymanager.getTransaction( ).begin( );
  //pote = sc.next();
  System.out.println(pote);
  quest.setCategory(Integer.parseInt(pote));
  pote = sc.next();
  System.out.println(pote);
  quest.setlevel(Integer.parseInt(pote));
  pote = sc.next();
  System.out.println(pote);
  quest.setQuestion(pote);
  pote = sc.next();
  System.out.println(pote);
  quest.setR1(pote);
  pote = sc.next();
  System.out.println(pote);
  quest.setR2(pote);
  pote = sc.next();
  System.out.println(pote);
  quest.setR3(pote);
  pote = sc.next();
  System.out.println(pote);
  quest.setCorrect(pote);
  System.out.println("End of line");
  sc.skip("[\r\n]");
  entitymanager.persist( quest );
  entitymanager.getTransaction( ).commit( );
  entitymanager.close( );
  quest_factory.close( );
}
while((pote = sc.next())!= null);
sc.close();
```

Error screenshot

[image]

Comment: Whatever it is, it is definitely not a ``[mcve]

Comment: Really? All Im trying to say is that Im Reading a csv file using a delimeter, once it gets to the lets String to be read on the line, it reads the last String and also the first one on the next line, all as one string. Thats why I´m trying to use the Skip method...

Comment: You give us to much code. Give as little as possible to understand the problem.

Comment: well from the sample code I posted, you can ignore the 'system.out.println's  they´re there just for debugging the rest is the method, I can´t take anything else out, other wise it wont make sense..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I´ve got the answer, in the last String I just use the nextLine() instead of next().

Answer (score 0):

The end of line character is different on different platforms. `\r\n` is on Windows, `\n` is on Linux, and `\r` is what's default on Mac OS. I wouldn't recommend explicitly specifying the end of line character(s) to skip. Try

```
while (scanner.hasNext()) {
    // other code

    if (scanner.hasNextLine())
        scanner.nextLine();
}
```

instead as this'll automatically sort out the platform dependent stuff, and be able to handle the end of file.

It could also be that you haven't actually reached the end of that line yet, but I can't tell you much without knowing what entries you actually have in your csv file

Comment: This is the file´s content:
35;2;questao1;resposta;resposta2;resposta3;rcorreta
5 lines with the samething on them, but you see once it gets to the last column it reads 'rcorreta35' because the delimiter is the ';' so 'rcorreta' and the number '35' is between two ';'... you get it? thats why I tried using the skip method..